# How to load a number of applications into a single page application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, reactjs, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I need to create a asp.net core application that serves a single page application. On the index.html page I will have several buttons and each button  is a link to another app in a different domain. When I click one of the buttons I want to load the app but in the URL the domain is the initial app. And the same behavior should happen with the other buttons I click.

So for example my main app is at http://mydomain1.com/app1 and the second app is at http://someotherdomain/app2, when I click the button I want to load app2 and the url changes to http://mydomain1.com/app2.

Since both app1 and app2 are single page applications they should work as expected but the URL makes it look like they are served from the same domain (mydomain1.com).

Also when the user uses the functionality of the single page app http://mydomain1.com/app2, all the web service calls go back to http://someotherdomain.

Is this possible?

The reason I am trying to solve this issue : we have a number of single page apps and we want to house them in one main app and use that to launch the other apps.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 6+, you can setup multiple applications. There are [some](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527) [tutorials](https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/) you can follow that show you how to set them up and even how to [connect it to ASP.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715608/asp-net-core-multiple-angular-app).

Comment: Thank you. What about React?

Comment: Would I be able to mix React and Angular apps or do I have to pick one for a multi app solution?

Comment: I haven't done this with React, but [there is a tutorial](https://medium.jonasbandi.net/hosting-multiple-react-applications-on-the-same-document-c887df1a1fcd) on how to do it.